# Transform list of possible pairs in distance matrix in R

Tags: r, list, transform, variable-types, distance-matrix

I have a series of elements A, B, C and D. For each possible pair (AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD), I have computed a distance measure and store in a vector at position x.

Position `x` is determined by the following loop: 
(`n` is number of elements, in this example case, 4)

```
 n=1
 for i in 1:(n-1)
     for j in (i+1):n
         distancevector[n] = distancemeasure
         n = n+1
```

What is the easiest way to transform `distancevector` into a distance matrix in R?

Example:

distancevector = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6)

what I want would be this distance matrix:

A    1        0.1    0.2     0.3

B    0.1    1        0.4     0.5

C    0.2    0.4     1        0.6

D    0.3    0.5     0.6     1

Comment: Could you provide an example? A way could be to cheat with the "dist" class that has a `as.matrix` method. I.e. assuming a distance vector `vec = runif(6)` see `as.matrix(structure(vec, class = "dist", Size = 4))`

Comment: just wrote the example in the main question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base` R we can try:

```
n <- 4
distancevector <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6)

D <- diag(n)
D[lower.tri(D)] <- distancevector
D[upper.tri(D)] <- t(D)[upper.tri(D)]

> D
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  1.0  0.1  0.2  0.3
[2,]  0.1  1.0  0.4  0.5
[3,]  0.2  0.4  1.0  0.6
[4,]  0.3  0.5  0.6  1.0
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I wanted :)